# How to show x grid line only to some y value in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

How to make **x-grid line** named **"Today"** to be shown only to some **y** value (for example **from y =0 to y=25**)

```
    grid: {

    x: {
        lines: [
            {value: 4, text: 'Today',position: 'start'},
            {value: 12}

        ]
    },
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/KrisKuliv/74fkuyw4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3.js does not support this behaviour. You can only customize these lines with own css classes which doesn't include the length of the lines because svg doesn't work this way.

The only way to get the wanted behaviour is using d3 directly. You can give your lines some classes to make them easier to select.

```
grid: {

    x: {
        lines: [
            {value: 4, text: 'Today',position: 'start', class: 'myClass'},
            {value: 12}

        ]
    }

d3.selectAll(".myClass")
```

I haven't done something like this yet but I hope this will help you.